# How to disable specific dates in bootstrap-datetimepicker-master?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM dd hh:ii P',
    startDate: "2016-08-19 10:00",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5],
    autoclose: true,    
});
```

How to disable specific date in datetime picker?

Comment: I think that library itself have example in github page(README) https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: its not give any example for disable specific dates..

Answer (score 7):

That will depend on which plugin you are using, there are several bootstrap-datetimepicker projects.

If bootstrap-datetimepicker-master is [this one](https://libraries.io/bower/bootstrap-datetimepicker-master), based on [this fork](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) you can use `datesDisabled`:

> **datesDisabled**
>
> String, Array. Default: []
>
> Array of date strings or a single date string formatted in the given
>   date format

You can check it out [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled).

If you are using other plugin you need to have a look to its docs, but I guees more of the projects have `datesDisabled` available.

Remember to specify the dates in the format that you have set, in your case: `'YYYY/MM/DD'`.

### Example:

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:ii',
    startDate: '2016/08/19 10:00',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5],
    datesDisabled: ['2016/08/20'],
    autoclose: true,    
});
```

Comment: yah,its correct datesDisabled but its through error,   bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1608 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts' of undefined

Comment: format: 'YYYY/MM/D',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5],
    datesDisabled:["2016-08-21"],

Comment: bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1491 Uncaught Error: Invalid format type.

Comment: That is because the formats are not matching. As I pointed out in my answer, if you pass `format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'` you need to pass `datesDisabled: ['2016/08/21']` and not `datesDisabled: ['2016-08-21']`

Answer (score 0):

I got the some problem and I think my format is matching

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    datesDisabled: ['2016-09-16'],
});
```