# Uncaught TypeError: option beforeShowDay is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried to remove some dates in datetimepicker. But it gives me this error.
**I haven't permission to add or update javascript libraries**.My requirement is only removeing these `disabledates`  dates. Please advise me on how to fix this issue without modifying the javascript libraries.
Thank you.

```
 var disabledates = ['2020-11-27','2020-11-28','2020-11-30']

 $('#Setdate').datetimepicker({
                minDate: yesterday,
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('MM/DD/YYYY', date);
                return [ disabledates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
                },
               
            }).on('dp.change',loadTeacherList);
```

Error:

```
bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: option beforeShowDay is not recognized!
    at Function.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.j.options (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8)
    at c (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.a.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.js:2), <anonymous>:8:27)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/14484159

Comment: Perhaps look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051207